# Two Dimensional Sort In Java(without .sort())

Tags: java, sorting

I have a final tomorrow and although I have found a work around, I would love an explanation from someone as to why the code shown below must be run twice to rearrange the list from 1,2,3 etc to 3,2,1.. if I use the sortColumn function only once it will return 3,1,2 etc.

```
public class test1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // TODO Test skills with sorting algorithms
      int[][] num = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
      int[][] newNum = sortColumn(num);
      // newNum = sortColumn(newNum);
      for (int row = 0; row < newNum.length; row++) {
          System.out.println(" ");
          for (int col = 0; col < newNum[0].length; col++) {
              System.out.print(newNum[row][col]);
          }
      }

  }

  static int[][] sortColumn(int[][] num) {
      int[][] colNum = num.clone();
      // System.out.println(colNum.length);
      // System.out.println(colNum[0].length);
      int temp;
      for (int row = colNum.length - 1; row > -1; row--) {
          for (int col = colNum[0].length - 2; col > -1; col--) {
              if (colNum[row][col] < colNum[row][(col + 1)]) {
                temp = colNum[row][col];
                colNum[row][col] = colNum[row][(col + 1)];
                colNum[row][(col + 1)] = temp;
              }
          }
      }

      return colNum;
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm starts with the second to last element of the array and compares it to the last element, so `2` is compared to `3` and thus they get swapped leaving you with 1, 3, 2.

Next you proceed to the first element of the array and compare it to the second element, so `1` is compared to `3` and again these two get swapped leaving you with 3, 1, 2.

However, without a second call to `sortColumn` the code never compares the `1` and the `2` so they are left as is.

The problem with calling `sortColumn` a second time is that if you add a fourth column (and it gets worse the more columns you add) you'll be back in the same boat: starting with 1, 2, 3, 4 and calling `sortColumn` twice yields 4, 3, 1, 2. In theory you might get away with calling `sortColumn` one less time than the number of columns but this gets inefficient when you get more than a few columns because you are re-comparing columns that have already been sorted into the right positions.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps to put it into perspective.  I guess it'll be about time to start using the .sort feature.